# find duplicates and merge their values in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table that contains a list of schools and names:

```
school    name    point
------------------------
first     dani    good
first     dani    precise
third     John    nice
first     dani    pro
third     John    cute
```

I want to end up with just one record for each school / name combination and merge the point values like this:

```
school    name    point
--------------------------------------
first     dani    good and precise and pro
third     John    cute and nice
```

Comment: do you want an actual new table where the data is formatted like that, or do you just need it in some sort of array to use inside your php code?

Comment: i want delete duplicates and remain one row with this updates

Comment: try explaining that you have duplicate points, which you don't want in your question. Also try to update your table with some duplicate rows and show the result you want as example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` like that to get the results :

```
SELECT school, name, GROUP_CONCAT(point SEPARATOR ' and ') points
FROM table
GROUP BY school, name
```

If it's ok and you want to replace your actually table with the results,
create the same table with another name tmptable for example.

```
INSERT INTO tmptable
SELECT school, name, GROUP_CONCAT(point SEPARATOR ' and ') points
FROM table
GROUP BY school, name;

DROP TABLE table;
RENAME TABLE tmptable TO table;
```

Here you see the result in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/845c4/2/0)

Comment: does not work, your code work if school value and name value be same but in my tables have different values

Comment: I don't think so... Have you tested ?

Comment: yes... i tested it and find the values that school and name are same, in my tables this values are different

Comment: @ebahi - your answer is also 100% correct . i dont know what happens

Comment: @BerndBuffen I'm guessing he wants `distinct` i.e. `group_concat( distinct point ...`

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample that will works for you

and a new one with DISTINCT

```
SELECT
  school,
  `name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT( `point` SEPARATOR ' and ')
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT school,`name`, `point` FROM groupme) AS result
GROUP BY school,`NAME`;
```

---

```
SELECT
  school,
  `name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT( `point` SEPARATOR ' and ')
FROM groupme
GROUP BY school,`name`;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select * from groupme;
+----+--------+------+---------+
| id | school | name | point   |
+----+--------+------+---------+
|  1 | first  | dani | good    |
|  2 | first  | dani | precise |
|  3 | third  | John | nice    |
|  4 | first  | dani | pro     |
|  5 | third  | John | cute    |
+----+--------+------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT school, `name` , GROUP_CONCAT( `point` SEPARATOR ' and ')
    -> FROM groupme
    -> GROUP BY school,`name`;
+--------+------+------------------------------------------+
| school | name | GROUP_CONCAT( `point` SEPARATOR ' and ') |
+--------+------+------------------------------------------+
| first  | dani | good and precise and pro                 |
| third  | John | nice and cute                            |
+--------+------+------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

Comment: find the rows that school and name are same, in my tables this values are different

Comment: i dont understand, have you tested. post your table

Comment: i have add one more sql with DISTINCT. so every point is only one time in the result

Answer (score 1):

**Using @ebahi's answer:**

Change the query into as mentioned by @fuzzytree:

```
SELECT school, name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct point SEPARATOR ' and ') points
FROM table
GROUP BY school, name
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/225d6/2/0) to see the result